# how can I test accepts_nested_attributes_for with Rspec Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec2

I have a model as follows:

```
class Greeting < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :headline, :icon, :content

  belongs_to :user


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, :reject_if => proc { |a| a[:name].blank? || a[:email].blank? }
```

How can I do an Rspec test for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here you have `Shoulda` macro for testing `accepts_nested_attributes_for`: http://mediumexposure.com/testing-acceptsnestedattributesfor-shoulda-macros/. It does not support any options (such as `:reject_if`), only bare `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

But for `:reject_if`, you can create a valid Greeting model with nested attributes for `User` but without `:name`. Then check if user has been saved, and then same with blank `:email`

So you can do something like this:

```
describe Greeting
  it { expect { Factory(:greeting, :user_attributes => Factory_attributes_for(:user)) }.to change(User, :count).by(1) }
  it { expect { Factory(:greeting, :user_attributes => Factory_attributes_for(:user, :name => '')) }.to_not change(User, :count) }
  it { expect { Factory(:greeting, :user_attributes => Factory.attributes_for(:user, :email => '')) }.to_not change(User, :count) }
end
```

Answer (score 34):

I just found this shoulda macro, seems like it works fine:

https://gist.github.com/1353500/bae9d4514737a5cd7fa7315338fdd9053dbff543

you should use it like this:

```
it{ should accept_nested_attributes_for :samples }
```